Find all points M such that MA<MB.
In the Euclidean affine plane $\mathbb{E}$, let $A$ and $B$ be two distinct points. Prove that the set {$M \in \mathbb{E} \mid MA < MB$} is a half-plane determined by the perpendicular bisector of segment $AB$ and includes point $A$.
Here's my answer, but I'm unsure how to prove it. I am not sure if we have solved the problem or if I should go into more detail about why $\cos(\phi) >0$.
We have :
$ MA  < MB$
$\Leftrightarrow MA^2 < MB^2 $
$\Leftrightarrow \overrightarrow{MA}^2 < \overrightarrow{MB}^2 $
$\Leftrightarrow \big(\overrightarrow{MI}+\overrightarrow{IA}\big)^2 < \big(\overrightarrow{MI}+\overrightarrow{IB}\big)^2 $
$\Leftrightarrow\overrightarrow{MI}^2 +2.\overrightarrow{MI}.\overrightarrow{IA}+\overrightarrow{IA}^2 <
\overrightarrow{MI}^2+2.\overrightarrow{MI}.\overrightarrow{IB} +\overrightarrow{IB}^2$
$\Leftrightarrow\overrightarrow{MI}.\overrightarrow{IA} <\overrightarrow{MI}.\overrightarrow{IB}$
$\Leftrightarrow \overrightarrow{MI}.(\overrightarrow{IA}-\overrightarrow{IB})< 0$
$ \Leftrightarrow \overrightarrow{MI}.\overrightarrow{BA}< 0 \text{ }(*) $
According to (*), we see that $M\ne I$. Besides, we have $\overrightarrow{MI}.\overrightarrow{BA} = MI.BA. \cos(\overrightarrow{MI}, \overrightarrow{BA} )$.
Since $\overrightarrow{MI}.\overrightarrow{BA} <0$, we imply that $ \cos(\overrightarrow{MI}, \overrightarrow{BA}) <0$.
As vectors $\overrightarrow{BA}$ and $\overrightarrow{IA}$ are pointing in the same direction, it can be concluded that $\cos(\overrightarrow{MI}, \overrightarrow{IA})<0$.
Therefore, $ \cos(\overrightarrow{IM}, \overrightarrow{IA})>0 $.
Assume that $\phi$ is the angle between two vectors $\overrightarrow{IM}$ and $\overrightarrow{IA}$. Since $\cos(\phi) >0$,$\phi \in \Big(0,\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)$.
Therefore, the set {$M \in \mathbb{E} \mid MA < MB$} is a half-plane determined by the perpendicular bisector of segment $AB$ and includes point $A$.

Let a point $M$ be in the same half-plane as $A$ w.r.t the perpendicular bisector of $AB$. Then $BM$ intersects with the perpendicular bisector at some point $N$. We have $AN=BN$, hence $\angle NAB=\angle NBA$. Hence $\angle MAB\gt \angle MBA$. Hence from the triangle $AMB$ we have $MB\gt MA$.
Points at perpendicular bisector are equidistant from $A$ and $B$. Points from the other half-plane are closer to $B$.
If $A, B, M$ lie in the same straight line, the same argument for a degenerate triangle still holds. Or an easy reasoning without triangles can be made for this case.

Thank you so much. Can you help me see if my answer is correct?

@ThanhThanh I find your reasoning very good, just a bit too complicated for this simple question.
